# my coding driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click(); is not executed in the test script

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am a new tester, I got two question regarding my test script, I  export my test script(export to Junit4 webdriver) from selenium ide and then paste it into my eclipse indigo. But when I run my test script, It will only run until
`driver.findElement(By.name("j_idt61")).click();`

After that line of code actually got one more line which is to click log out link `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();`

but selenium seems can't find linkText "`Logout`"..

this is my code

```
package admin ;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class login {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = " here I put my website URL";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/admin/pages/login.xhtml");

    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("sasa");
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("sasasamsudin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_idt61")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

 public boolean isElementPresent(By id) {
    try {
      driver.findElements(By.id("J_idt16:J_idt30"));
      return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

 public boolean isElementVisible(By id)
 {

     return driver.findElement(By.id("J_idt16:J_idt30")).isDisplayed();

 }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {`enter code here`
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alert.getText();
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Please anyone help me .I just start my work and really need this automation testing to be working properly ..THANKS :)

Comment: Please put the HTML you are running against or try to reproduce this with a public facing website. We can do nothing without it.

Comment: @Arran , put the HTML from the ide ? is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Logout"));` instead, because there could be other/whitespace characters that you aren't seeing. `partialLinkText()` only checks that the link contains your text, but `linkText()` checks if the link's whole text is equal to your text.

Also, be sure that the element containing the text "Logout" is an `<a></a>` - because `linkText()` and `partialLinkText(`) won't check any other kind of element.

EDIT:

If the problem is that the element exists but isn't visible, then you'll need to wait for it to become visible:

```
// find the element
WebElement anchor = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Logout"));

// create a wait with 10-second timeout
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// wait for the element to become visible
anchor = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(anchor));

// proceed with test...
```

Or, if the element isn't going to eventually become visible on its own, you can force it to be visible:

```
// find the element
WebElement anchor = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Logout"));

// execute JavaScript to change the element's visibility
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", anchor);

// proceed with test...
```

Comment: hai @Pat Meeker 

I changed my coding to paritalLinkText but still got error below : 

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with  

I checked the ""logout" is an <a></a> ..            

<a onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt16'),{'j_idt16:j_idt30':'j_idt16:j_idt30'},'');return false" href="#">Logout</a>

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself.  I exported a set of tests which work fine within the Selenium IDE but when exported no longer seem to work.  You'll have to excuse my code examples as I'm working in Python not Java.  So in my case I had

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Logout").click()
```

which I changed to this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Logout')]").click()
```

The same also applies to whenever you use "By.LINK_TEXT" which just swap it for "By.XPATH" and then update the parameter with an xpath based parameter.

Hope that helps.

Mr-F

Answer (score 0):

You may have one of thoses problems:

1-The component who's linkText= "logout" is not already enabled so you should wait until the component will be enabled

2-It's discourage to use classname or linkedtext... because it may be present in other places in the page, so it's preferable to use By.ID or By.XPath

3-The component "LogOut" should be in the same frame as the previous components

Good luck :-)